# How to compress image using Laravel Package Image intervention

Tags: laravel, image, resize, image-compression, intervention

Sorry for this stupidity question. **I'm developing a classified website in Laravel here it is link [salebaba.com](https://salebaba.com) Please visit**

When users post an Ad I'm creating 3 sizes of images (Original , Mid , Thumb) for optimizing my website speed. But Now I want to compress image when it is uploading. I'm using Laravel Image intervention  to resize image.

**How can I compress image using Laravel or Image intervention to optimize Images?**

Your suggestions are important

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use

> public Intervention\Image\Image encode([mixed $format, [int $quality]])

```
->...        // any other methods from image intervention
->encode('jpg', 75);
```

The quality parameter is optional but is required in case of jpg.So you can check the format if it is jpg or not.

You can read more about it from [encode docs](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode)